# Is there any onResourceTimeout equivalent in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, timeout, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like to abort running casper when it takes long to open a page. In PhantomJS, you can set a page setting called resourceTimeout. This property  defines the timeout after which any resource requested will stop trying and proceed with other parts of the page. 
As I checked with CasperJS documentations, this property of a page is not supported in CasperJS. I know that we can use of stepTimeout option to have a control on the time spent in each step but I don't want to set a global value to affect all the steps. I want to limit just the page open step of the code. 
Is there any equivalent setting in CasperJS to do that? or Any other suggestions to stop pages which take long to load?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, so you can simply use the underlying `page` instance to register to this event by accessing `casper.page`.

The `page` instance is not created until `casper.start()` is called, so you need to register the event as soon as the page is created in the `page.created` event:

```
casper.on("page.created", function(){
    this.page.onResourceTimeout = function(request){
        // do whatever you need to do
    };
});

casper.start(url, then).run();
```

It's unlikely that you would need it (multiple different event handlers), but you can also use CasperJS' event system:

```
casper.on("page.created", function(){
    casper.page.onResourceTimeout = function(request){
        casper.emit("resource.timeout", request);
    };
});

casper.on("resource.timeout", function(request){
    // do whatever you need to do
});

casper.start(url, then).run();
```

Comment: The only question remains is that, how should I set the value of "resourceTimeout"? in PhantomJS , this value should be passed to the open function (as part of the page settings) and these settings apply only during the initial call to the page.open function. so subsequent modification of the settings object will not have any impact. So, how should I set this value for a page before calling casper.start or casper.open (when there is no page available)?

Comment: As I said, there is no `page` instance before `start` is called. It is created *during* `casper.start()`. But as soon as it is created the `page.created` callback is triggered and the `onResourceTimeout ` event handler can be registered. This will always happen before a resource actually times out. Even if it is the initial page load.